# Start/stop postgres per project

Tags: postgresql, foreman, procfile

I have several projects that use different versions of Postgres. We're using the [asdf plugin](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-postgres) to configure them. It's annoying to have to start and stop Postgres each time I move to different project. Is there some way to automate this? I was looking at adding it to our development `Procfile`, but since the `pg_ctl` process exits immediately after starting the server, `foreman` also exits.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to add an alias that starts the database before running `foreman` and shuts it down afterwards. It's not perfect, since it means I need to boot up the server in order to run the tests:

```
alias fsd="pg_ctl start && foreman start -f Procfile.dev; pg_ctl stop"
```